Why matplotlib extends figure size when using `fig.add_axes` in jupyter?
I'm using matplotlib (v 3.8.0) in jupyter (lab). I have a subplot of fixed size:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(8,4))

resulting in the following panels.

So far so good. But if I use fig.add_axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(8,4))
cax = fig.add_axes([0., 0., 0.02, 0.7] )  # [left, bottom, width, height]

matplotlib produces a larger figure:

with the new axis misplaced. According to this answer, add_axes should create a new axis starting from the lower left corner (0,0) and extend it by 8*0.02 = .16 horizontally and 4*.7 = 2.8 vertically. Why it is not the case? What am I missing here?
For background, I need the additional axis to for colorbar.
NOTE: stackoverflow display the images as if they have the same width. But the actual images are indeed of different size.
